# Matching a value and replace the data in the row

Tags: function, excel-formula, matching

I need a function that will replace the data in a 2d array with the data of another 2d array.

[Excel Sheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fpblw.png)

In the image, the table on the far left side is the where I want to replace the data as well as keep the order the same. The data in Columns D & E is the data from the table on the far left that I want to replace. The data in columns G & H is the values with the replaced values next to it that I want to have replace in the original table. Is there a Function or macro that could be made to do this?

I have already tried a combination of the `FILTER` and `MATCH` functions. I experimented with using `VLOOKUP` but got confused on how to implement it.

Comment: To be clear, you want the data in Column H to overwrite the data in Column2 (Column B) just for the items that match and the rest remains as is? I'd consider using a helper column pulling in the values and use an iferror to pull the original data. In C2 `=iferror(vlookup(A2,$G$1:$H$7,2,0),B2)`, you can then copy and paste the values over column B and delete the helper column. The important thing for this to work would be to high the data in column G and convert it from Text to Number, so it recognizes the data as matching.

Comment: I love you. That worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Using a helper column pulling in the values and use an `iferror` to pull the original data.

In `C2`, `=iferror(vlookup(A2,$G$1:$H$7,2,0),B2)`, you can then copy and paste the values over column B and delete the helper column.

The important thing for this to work would be to **highlight the data in column G and convert it from Text to Number**, so it recognizes the data as matching.